# Remove row in table (pgfplotstable)

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am using `pgfplotstable`, I read a data file and I want to create a table without several rows.
To do this, I am trying to use `every row no XX/.style={output empty row}` (where `XX` is the number of the row) but it doesn't work. `output empty row` seems to work only for the header.

Do you have any idea to do this?

Comment: See the example of `row predicate` in the pgfplotstable manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found an easy solution: the command `skip rows between index={begin}{end}` allows to remove rows. See page 41 of the [pgfplotstable manual](http://mirrors.linsrv.net/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplotstable.pdf).